# How to write query to fetch product subcategory name in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am creating three table subcategory,product_details,orders and i am inserting product_id,qty,price of purchase user in, separated format in table and i want to fetch name product name from subcategory plz need query structure check output show only first item name second name is not showing

query:

```
$data = DB::table('orders')
                ->join('users','users.id','=','orders.user_id')
               ->join('product_details','product_details.product_id','=','orders.product_id')
               ->join('useraddress','useraddress.address_id','=','orders.useraddress_id')
               ->join('subcategory','subcategory.sub_id','=','product_details.sub_id')
               ->select('product_details.*','orders.*','subcategory.name_of_subcategory','users.*','useraddress.*')
               ->get();
        return view('customer_wise_sales_report',['data'=>$data]);
```

1)subcategory
[image]

2)product_details
[image]

3)orders 
[image]

4)output 
[image]

Comment: are you using eloquent ORM or using query builder?

Comment: what have you tried so far?? and your question is not quite clear. please edit your question with what you have tried and the logic.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon hello sir i am stored product_id in third table as , separated format of second table and second table is depend on first table, I want to fetch subcategory name from first table as 1,2=>face wash,face & body scrub  I am updateing query witch gives only face wash second item not showing. check query

Answer (score 0):

How with this?

```
SELECT orders.*, subcategory.name_of_subcategory
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN product_details ON product_details.product_id = orders.product_id
LEFT JOIN subcategory ON subcategory.sub_id = product_details.sub_id;
```

Comment: it gives only first item name second item name can not shown